# How to send same data from one Fragment to two other different fragments using EventBus 3

Tags: android, android-fragments, greenrobot-eventbus

I'm using EventBus 3 to send data between Fragments. I have sent data from Fragment A with EventBus.getDefault.post(etc) and successfully receiving data in Fragment B.

Now when I try to get the same data of Fragment A in Fragment C. Nothing is displaying in Fragment C. No error. May be the subscriber not working. Please guide me how I can get the same data from Fragment A to Fragment B and C with EventBus.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
   you can try this way add dependency inside your build gradle file.

   compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'

  in fragment A override methods like this.send data like this call in your 
  method from  where you want to send data.


   EventBus.getDefault().post(new String("Notification"));

   @Override
   public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getFriendFromServer();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}


@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void toChangeSearchFocus(String event) {

}
```

in fragment B

```
@Override
 public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
 }

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}


@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void toChangeSearchFocus(String event) {
     // here you will get your data.
}
```